# How to remove # sign in input type in edittext in android

Tags: android

Hi I had added **android:inputType="number"** in  Edittext. I want add **"+"** sign also.
I want nothing except **"+"** sign and **"number"** as a input.User willnot be able to add **#** sign.
Is there any way?

Comment: What about `-`?

Comment: no other character, like +91***** as in phone number

Answer (score 0):

I would get the user halfway there by specifying

```
android:inputType="phone"
android:hint="+1235554444"
```

and then programmatically checking that their input follows your required template, since the phone input type does allow #.

```
//First ensure the input starts with "+"
if(!phoneString[0].equals("+"){
    //Error
}

for(i = 0; i < phoneString.length() ; i++){
    if(phoneString[i].equals("#"){
        //Error
}
```

Add any other error checks you can think of.

Comment: Its ok, but I dont want to show "#"  in a key board.

Comment: @Kush I think you would have to write a custom keyboard then.

Comment: Thanks, @Emily but this is lengthy solution.